# Java Apache POI - save Word with new version in file system ober application

Tags: java-8, apache-poi

I have this usecase for my web application (Java8 in Backend and AngularJS in frontend): download word file, edit this word file and if users click the save button of Microsoft Word than a new version of this word document should be stored over application at hard disk. 
I have not found any information doing so but I know that it works (in another application).
Does anyone have any information to implement this or is there a different framework which supports that usecase?

Comment: Alfresco supports it - [Alfresco Office Services](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/aos-intro.html) - maybe use that instead?

Comment: I know Alfresco and I know there is this possiblilty, that was the reason of my question - I need it in my own application. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word is able to open, edit and save files from a WebDav 2 capable server.

We had the same challenge in our company and our research resulted in 2 options:

1. [milton.io](http://milton.io)
2. [Apache Jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)

**Opion 1** has the huge benefit of being ready to run out-of-the-box, meaning, that you just have to call a simple API, listen for the open/close event and that's it. The big disadvantage of option 1 is, that milton supports WebDav 2 only in the paid commercial version.

**Option 2** is licensed under the Apache license, so you can just use it. Jackrabbit is one of the reference implementations of the Java Content Repository specification ([JSR-170](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=170)). This comes with the benefit, that once you have to, you can exchange it for whatever reason, more or less flawlessly. The big con is, that JCR is not meant to just put some stuff into it and retrieve it elsewhere. Nevertheless it comes with a WebDav servlet, you will have to spent some time modifying that servlet for your needs.

To be able to react to the user opening, saving and closing the word document, you have to override `doLock`, `doPut` and `doUnlock` methods of the AbstractWebDavServlet.

We chose option 2, because this gave us the opportunity to get in touch with JCR (which will reduce introduction time in a future project) and we hadn't have to spent a lot of money for the library.

Comment: Thanks a lot andred! It helped a lot!